# Secondary navbar not aligning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the  second navbar to align on the right, I have tried adding `float:right` and  have tried adding a margin on the right to space out the words but  does not work. Tried removing the nav tag and replacing it with `section` but it does not work.

```css
/* NAV ON TOP*/
.pagetopTop{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.topNav{
  display: flex;
    float: right;
}

.Topspan{
  margin: var(--size-10);
}

/*navbar*/


.navbar .container{
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
   display:flex
}

.navbar-brand{
  height: var(--size-50);
  margin-top: var(--size-40);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-nav{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.navbar-nav li{
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

body{
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: var(--font-color-base);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
  ::after,
  ::before{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  a{ text-decoration: none;}

  p{ margin-top: 0;}

  h2{
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
  img{
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;
  }

  .container{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="pagetopTop" class="pagetopTop">
    <div class="container">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
      <span class="Topspan">Main Demos</span>

      <ul class="topNav">
        <li class="nav-link">
          <span class="Topspan">Demos</span>
          <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <span class="Topspan">Docs</span>
          <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <nav id="Nav" class="navbar nav">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="" class="">
      <img src="Week5saasappassets-210323-142515 (1)/Week-5-saas-app-assets/project_logo/logo.svg" alt="Company logo" class="navbar-brand">
    </a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">Learn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">Price</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-link">
          <a href="#">Hire us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Maybe because of the margins or parent elements overlapping each other.

[image]

want to move the ul list to the other side beneath demos and space it out

Comment: Hello Tareef can you add expected output image in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here, in terms of HTML semantics, it doesn't make a lot of sense to use `<section>` for a nav menu. The [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) represents a generic standalone section of a document, which doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it. A page without content and only a navigation menu wouldn't make very much sense.

Use a more semantic element like [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) which represents a section of a page whose purpose is to provide navigation links, either within the current document or to other documents. At worse, a division element `<div>` which doesn't have semantic meaning would make more sense than a `<section>` for a navigation menu. Also, you have `display: flex` and `float: right` on the `.topNav` container. Flexbox is the "newer" way to distribute space for items along a single axis so use one or the other, not both.

> Instead of using a float to create layouts by floating elements to the left or the right, flexbox allows you to create layouts by aligning items to a single axis. The axis can be horizontal or vertical. It is best used for distributing space for items in the same axis

Your using a bunch of [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icons but didn't include the `<script>` tag in your example so none of them rendered. Next, the `position: fixed` on the `<section>` container paired with absolute positioning of the `<li>` elements, this is causing some of the menu items to overlap since your taking the content out of the "normal flow". Unless that was intended, I'm not sure what the exact "expected output" is since you didn't include a picture.

For positioning two elements at opposite sides in a row, just use a Flexbox layout to distribute "space between" the two nav menus in the `<body>` using `justify-content: space-between`. I added a nested `<div>` to the `<body>` that will act as the flex container containing the two `<nav>` menus. You can also vertically align flex items (e.g. the two nav menus) along the cross-axis with `align-items: center`. I will let you take it from here to style the nav menus on each side of the viewport how you would like.

```css
/* NAV ON TOP*/

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.pagetopTop{
    /*position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;*/
    z-index: 500;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.topNav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.Topspan{
  margin: var(--size-10);
}

/*navbar*/


.navbar .container{
  /*top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;*/
  z-index: 500;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.navbar-brand{
  height: var(--size-50);
  margin-top: var(--size-40);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-nav{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}


.navbar-nav li{
  align-items: center;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

body{
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: var(--font-color-base);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
*,
::after,
::before{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a{ text-decoration: none;}

p{ margin-top: 0;}

h2{
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none;
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <nav id="pagetopTop" class="pagetopTop">
      <div class="container">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
        <span class="Topspan">Main Demos</span>
        <ul class="topNav">
          <li class="nav-link">
            <span class="Topspan">Demos</span>
            <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link">
            <span class="Topspan">Docs</span>
            <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <nav id="Nav" class="navbar nav">
      <div class="container">
      <a href="" class="">
        <img src="https://dynamic.brandcrowd.com/asset/logo/8cb54db0-7219-4bf6-bba3-1c9e94078516/logo?v=4" width="60" height="60" alt="Company logo" class="navbar-brand">
      </a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Learn</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Price</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Hire us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
    <!-- Font Awesome Script -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e03d7ac5cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```